# Process substitution capture stderr

Tags: bash, stderr, process-substitution

For this question I will use `grep`, because its usage text prints to stderr:

```
$ grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

You can capture stdout easily with process substitution:

```
$ read b < <(echo hello world)
```

However stderr slips past the process substitution and prints to the console:

```
$ read b < <(grep)
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

I would like to capture stderr using process substitution. I am using this now:

```
$ grep 2> log.txt

$ read b < log.txt
```

but I am hoping to avoid the temp file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Redirect the stderr of your command to stdout:

```
$ read "b" < <(grep 2>&1)
$ echo "$b"
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

Though the conventional way to save the output of a command to a variable in Bash is by using `$()`:

```
$ b=$(grep 2>&1)
$ echo "$b"
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
```

Comment: And maybe he would like to erase what went to stdout before, to capture ONLY stderr? I do.

Comment: `read "b" < <(grep 2>&1)` reads only the first line to $b, `b=$(grep 2>&1)` reads the whole output

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep 2> >(sed 's/e/E/g';)
```

You can capture ***grep***'s stdout and pipe it to ***sed*** but, I don't know why (nor how to avoid it) it needs an extra INTRO to return control and display the prompt.

**Edit**: You can fix that mismatch like this:

```
$ grep 2> >(sed 's/e/E/g';); sync
```

Comment: You are almost right. You have an unnecessary `;` in your process substitution. That's why you need `; sync` to fix this hang up. Just try: `grep 2> >(sed 's/e/E/g')`, and you will have straightaway an output.

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution for a whole subshell is to use `exec` to redirect its standard error.

If, instead of the OP's example based on `grep` being a single command, you had a sequence of commands in the subshell then you can redirect the standard error of the whole subshell like this:

```
b=$(cat <(
    exec 2>&1
    echo "standard output"
    echo "standard error" 1>&2
   ))    

echo $b
```

which puts the output of standard output and standard error into the variable `$b`:

```
standard output standard error
```

The `echo` statements are just examples to output something to each of standard output and standard error.